# Update the content of a table in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datagridview

I am trying to update a record in .Net. I can't figure it out how to do it. I need to  specify that I have a DataGridView that displays all the records, and when I click a cell, it shows in separate TextBoxes the content of all columns. So that is I am trying to do, when I modify the TextBoxes and click the Button for Update, to update the row which contains the clicked cell.
I have tried to do this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] row_update = ds.Tables["Plane"].Select("airline_id = " + aidbox.Text);
        try
        {
            row_update["airline_id"] = int.Parse(aidbox.Text);
            row_update["plane_id"] = int.Parse(pid_box.Text);
            row_update["name"] = name_box.Text;
            row_update["model"] = model_box.Text;
            row_update["f_seats"] = int.Parse(fc_box.Text);
            row_update["s_seats"] = int.Parse(sc_box.Text);
            row_update["b_seats"] = int.Parse(bs_box.Text);
            row_update["p_weight"] = float.Parse(weight_box.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

            try
                {
                    builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(data_adapter);
                    data_adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();

                    data_adapter.Update(ds, "Plane");

                }
                catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            }

        }
```

but I get this error `Table doesn't have a primary key.` in this line `DataRow row_update = ds.Tables["Plane"].Rows.Find(aidbox.Text);` Here I am trying to find the row that has the id in the aidbox (because I assume that the id is unique and never changes only the other values). 
Can anyone help me please with this

Answer (score 0):

DataRows.Find method [Gets a specified DataRow using the PrimaryKey index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
If you cannot define a primary key for the datatable then could use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it accepts any column in the filter expression

Answer (score 0):

`DataRowCollection.Find` requires a primary key on the `DataTable`.  Set the `PrimaryKey` property by creating an array of `DataColumns`. [See the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx).  Or just use `Select` instead.

Comment: My table has a primary key. It is "plane_id". How could I change whith the select?

Comment: I mean don't use Find unless you are querying on your primary key.  To search airline_id, use `ds.Tables["Plane"].Select("airline_id = " + airbox.Text)`

Comment: Can you please check the updated code. I dont'n know why it gives me this error that cannot implicity convert type string to int...

Comment: @user3421241 check whether there is any type mismatch.

Comment: @user3421241 which line is giving you that conversion error?

Comment: Select returns an array of DataRow objects.  You need to pick one out by index ... then use your column name as the index on the single DataRow.  For example: `var row = row_update[0]; row["airline_id"]`

Comment: Can you help me with an example?

Comment: Work with what I gave you in the last comment.  Struggle with it for a while.  If you can't get it working, then revise your question with new info.  That is how you'll learn.

Comment: Your example helped me but now I get this The "DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized." on this line "data_adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();"

Answer (score 0):

Your previous find() may work through this code,

```
DataColumn[] temp = new DataColumn[1];
temp[0] = ds.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];
ds.Tables["Plane"].PrimaryKey = temp;
DataRow row_update = ds.Tables["Plane"].Rows.Find(aidbox.Text);
```